# Dart Web Client Application using Google Play Game Services Auth Exception

Tags: dart, google-play-games

I need to develop a WebClient in Dart using Google Play Game Services api. The Following source raises an Exception when i'm running it in Dartium.
What's the problem in here?

**Exception:**

> Refused to set unsafe header "user-agent" Refused to set unsafe header
>   "content-length" Failed to load resource: the server responded with a
>   status of 401 (Unauthorized)
>   https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/leaderboards/XXXXXX?alt=json
>   Exception: Uncaught Error: Access was denied (www-authenticate header
>   was: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/AuthSubRequest",
>   error=invalid_token).

```dart
    import 'dart:html';

    import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_browser.dart';

    import 'package:googleapis/games/v1.dart';


    void main() {

      var id = new ClientId("xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com", "xxxx");
      var scopes = [GamesApi.PlusLoginScope, GamesApi.GamesScope];

      // Initialize the browser oauth2 flow functionality.
      createImplicitBrowserFlow(id, scopes).then((BrowserOAuth2Flow flow) {
        flow.clientViaUserConsent().then((AuthClient client) {
          // Authenticated and auto refreshing client is avaliable in [client].
          var game = new GamesApi(client);

          game.leaderboards.get("XXXXXX").then( (Leaderboard leaderBoard) {
           print(leaderBoard.id);
          });
         /* game.leaderboards.list().then((onValue) {
            print(onValue);
          });*/
          client.close();
          flow.close();
        });
      });

    }
```

Comment: This source is ok, the problem was missing configuration on playstore games services.

Comment: Could you please answer your own question with how you fixed it and then accept the answer?  It will help future people with the same problem.

Comment: Simply the authorization for my Dart app was missing in the PlayStore Game Services section. You have to authorize every app using your defined services.